# How to add a input field and save the value to the database to the new order creating page in admin side

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order, custom-field

I have a field in the front end order creating page as order instructions for giving user to give any  instructions, so i wanted to add this field also to the admin side on order creation. how to add the field in the order creating page in admin side?.

Comment: Have you tried My suggested solution and if it help you then mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I found A very Good article which is showing step by step process for the same 
Might be you follow the same and able to add

http://www.demagento.com/tutorial-magento-add-custom-field-to-order-checkout-page/